# trim base64 string by ltrim() missing character in PHP

Tags: php, base64, trim

here is a `base64` code begin with: `data:image/png;base64`.  I use `ltrim()` like this:

```
$base64_data='data:image/png;base64,iVboR....';
$base64_data = ltrim($base64_data,'data:image/png;base64,');
```

but the result is wrong whitout character "i".  is "VboR...."
why?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the purpose of the trim() function... the second argument isn't an exact match string to remove, it's an unordered series of letters to remove

Comment: Why not simply use [substr()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to remove the initial part of the string? `$base64_data = substr($base64_data, strlen('data:image/png;base64,'));`

Comment: but the result is nearly correct, just without "i"  and when i change code like ltrim($base64_data,'data:image/png;base64');  thus, the result is right,no character missed

Comment: The point is that you completely misunderstand what [ltrim()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php) is actually doing.... and it is not the correct function for what you're trying to achieve

Comment: i use the substr finally, i just check out what's wrong with the trim

Comment: read the note on the `trim()` page http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for fun, if you know the whole substring you want removed, just replace it :)

```
$base64_data='data:image/png;base64,iVboR....';
$base64_data = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,','',$base64_data);
```

**Output**

```
iVboR....
```

Why do you *incorrectly* want to trim out the a whole substring? Trim is not for that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `substr` not `ltrim`

```
$base64_data = substr($base64_data, 22);
```